# Ubuntu 16.04 sftp and vscode ssh not working

Tags: ssh, sftp

I use MobaXterm on my windows PC to connect to an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I worked well until recently I found that SFTP is not working, so my MobaXterm sftp pane is disappear.

To make sure that is not MobaXterm issue, I also download FileZilla to test SFTP, not working either.

Also, I tried to use VSCode on my windows PC with extension "Remote-SSH" to connect to my Ubuntu machine, but it keeps showing this error:

[image]

I am not sure if these connection problems I mentioned above are came from after

1. I installed zsh on my Ubuntu machine,
2. I installed XRDP but uninstall after.

Any help I would be very appreciate.